# gcp cloud postgresql one backend service is unable to connect while the others do

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am working with devops infrastructure using cloudbuild on google cloud platform, having three services which running inside dokcer container of gke cluster.

**1. identityServer**

```
$kubectl describe pod identity-6ddb69c646-gcrgr
Name:         identity-6ddb69c646-gcrgr
Namespace:    default
Status:       Running
IP:           10.4.1.24
```

**2. tenant**

```
$kubectl describe pod tenant-5c4b4d55dd-jvdbh
Name:         tenant-5c4b4d55dd-jvdbh
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.4.3.20
```

**3. appResource**

```
$kubectl describe pod 
Name:         appResource-86b7c8c989-bmv8x
Namespace:    default
Status:       Running
IP:           10.4.2.43
```

Which **identityServer** and **tenant** connect to **identityDb** using private ip address, unfortunately the **tenant** turned out.
***error connection timeout***
`$kubectl logs tenant-5c4b4d55dd-jvdbh`

> ===> NpSqlConnection test: ...
> ===> NpSqlConString: User ID =postgres;Password=password;Server=10.15.128.10;Port=5432;Database=identityDb;
> PostgreSQL error: The operation has timed out.
> Unhandled exception. System.Exception: The operation has timed out.

While the other two connected successfully.
**identityServer**
`$kubectl logs identity-6ddb69c646-gcrgr`

> ===> NpSqlConnection test: ...
> ===> NpSqlConString: User ID =postgres;Password=password;Server=10.15.128.10;Port=5432;Database=identityDb;
> PostgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 10.17 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by Debian clang version 10.0.1 , 64-bit

to make it clear, I added the same connection to **appResource** too.
**appResource**
`$kubectl logs appResource-86b7c8c989-bmv8x`

> ===> NpSqlConnection test: ...
> ===> NpSqlConString: User ID =postgres;Password=password;Server=10.15.128.10;Port=5432;Database=identityDb;
> PostgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 10.17 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by Debian clang version 10.0.1 , 64-bit

TestConnection function c# ClassTest.cs

```
public static void TestDbConnection()
   {
        Console.WriteLine("===> NpSqlConnection test: ...");
        try
        {
            var constr = "User ID =postgres;Password=password;Server=10.15.128.10;Port=5432;Database=identityDb;";
            Console.WriteLine($"===> NpSqlConString: {constr}");
            using var connector = new NpgsqlConnection(constr);
            connector.Open();
            var sql = "SELECT version()";
            using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connector);
            var version = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"PostgreSQL version: {version}");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
```

Program.cs of every csharp project

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassTest.TestDbConnection();
            //CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
    }
```

**Note**

- even if I create a new database and/or remove the other two working services, the **tenant** still unable to connect anyway.
- working fine in local dev.
- gcp VPC Network "default"
- using gcp $300 free credit, learning/testing so I have my own limit of using gcp.

any suggestions it would be appreciated. thanks.

**EDIT**
*gke cluster configuration*
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the firewall rules?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for your attention, i am sorry but do you mean firewall of VPC network or running node?
i did tested telnet inside container with "kubectl exec podname -- /bin/bash" and it is connected.

Comment: I mean the VPC firewall rules. But if you can telnet it, there is no network issue. I don't know about your cluster configuration. The only thing I notice in the namespace of the tenant not mentionned

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you. for namespace were automatically created, I use default namespace just test and learn, so I left it blank for all yaml configurations. 
I will try to provide namspace manually and test again to make it clear.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the namespace does not matter after manually provided and still having the same error.
I edited my question adding cluster configuration.

Comment: Can you try to deploy your tenant pod but with another working image (identityServer or AppResource)? There is maybe a problem in the pod configuration.

Comment: That is good idea, I put "tenant" image to identity deploy and it works. You saved me, I have tried verifying the deploy config between these three services over and over again but have not tried this trick. 
For now I changed the "tenant" service port number and it works but do not know why the previous ports (8380:80, 8383:443) did not work.
Anyway 8580:80, 8585:443 these two working fine.
Thank you for your help @guillaumeblaquiere